# Jquery and JavaScript Show and Hide Select with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if i select climbn i want to hide climt and climb
here is my code and javascript below

HTML:

```
<span id="climt" class="themesegclass" style="display: none;">
  <span id="outputimgsrc"></span>
</span>
<span id="climbn" class="themesegclass" style="display: none;">
  <span id="outputimgsrc"></span>
</span>
<Select id="themeselector">
  <option value="climb">Classic - Image Bottom</option>
  <option value="climt">Classic - Image Top</option>
  <option value="climbn">Classic - Image Below Name</option>
</Select>
```

Java script:

```
$(function() {
  var inputimgsrc = document.getElementById("inputimgsrc").value;
  document.getElementById("outputimgsrc").innerHTML =  "<img src=" + inputimgsrc + " style='width: 100px; height: 100px;'>";

  $('#themeselector').change(function () {
    $('.themesegclass').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: span id with id="outputimgsrc"> wont show

Comment: `"<img src=" + inputimgsrc + "` logic error, no quotes for tag attribute

Comment: You have `id="outputimgsrc"` twice. What do you expect `document.getElementById("outputimgsrc")` to do?

Comment: im trying to reuse the image inside document.getElementById("outputimgsrc") and display it inside another div.

Answer (score -1):

I am not able to just add a comment, but can it be as simple as the fact that you are using the same id (outputimgsrc) for two spans?

```
    <span id="climt" class="themesegclass" style="display: none;"><span id="outputimgsrc"></span></span> <span id="climbn" class="themesegclass" style="display: none;"><span id="outputimgsrc"></span></span>
```

Comment: yes i just want to call the image inputted by the user and change its location thats why i made a select and  call it in a div to change its location.

Comment: It would seem that simply changing to a class, and set the content:url(). You should then be able to toggle the surrounding span id display styles as needed.